# How to filter with numpy on 2D array using np.where

Tags: python, numpy, filtering

I read the numpy doc and np.where takes 1 argument to return row indices when the condition is matching..

[numpy.where(condition, [x, y, ]/)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where)

In the context of multi dimensional array I want to find and replace when the condition is matching
this is doable with some other params from the doc `[x, y, ]  are replacement values`

Here is my data structure :
`my_2d_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`

Here is how I filter a column with python `my_2d_array[:,1]`

Here is how I filter find/replace with numpy :

```
indices = np.where( my_2d_array[:,1] == 4, my_2d_array[:,1]  , my_2d_array[:,1] )
```

(when the second column value match 4 invert the value in column two with column one)

So its hard for me to understand why the same syntax `my_2d_array[:,1]` is used to filter a whole column in python and to designate a single row of my 2D array for numpy where the condition is matched

Comment: In that `where` line, the `x,y` arguments are the same; what's that supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Your array:

```
In [9]: arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) 
In [10]: arr
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Testing for some value:

```
In [11]: arr==4
Out[11]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True]])
```

testing one column:

```
In [12]: arr[:,1]
Out[12]: array([2, 4])    
In [13]: arr[:,1]==4
Out[13]: array([False,  True])
```

As documented, `np.where` with just one argument is just a call to `nonzero`, which finds the index(s) for the `True` values:

So for the 2d array in [11] we get two arrays:

```
In [15]: np.nonzero(arr==4)
Out[15]: (array([1], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```

and for the 1d boolean in [13], one array:

```
In [16]: np.nonzero(arr[:,1]==4)
Out[16]: (array([1], dtype=int64),)
```

That array can be used to select a row from `arr`:

```
In [17]: arr[_,1]
Out[17]: array([[4]])
```

If used in the three argument `where`, it selects elements between the 2nd and 3rd arguments.  For example, using arguments that have nothing to do with `arr`:

```
In [18]: np.where(arr[:,1]==4, ['a','b'],['c','d'])
Out[18]: array(['c', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```

The selection gets more complicated if the arguments differ in shape; then the rules of `broadcasting` apply.

So the basic point with `np.where` is that all 3 arguments are first evaluated, and passed (in true python function fashion) to the `where` function.  It then selects elements based on the `cond`, returning a new array.

That `where` is functionally the same as this list comprehension (or an equivalent `for` loop):

```
In [19]: [i if cond else j for cond,i,j in zip(arr[:,1]==4, ['a','b'],['c','d'])]
Out[19]: ['c', 'b']
```